# Transferring mxd file from one system to another using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4

[image]

When I transfer one mxd file from ArcMap 10.4.1 to another system, the file was added but I am not able to see content.  I am getting as per added pic name error.

What should I do?

Comment: Please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/230797/edit) your question and specify where your data is stored. Local drive, network drive, enterprise geodatabase...?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [tour]. One of the principal differences between CAD and GIS is that map projects do not contain spatial data, just *references* to that data. When you move the project, you also need to make sure the data remains available.  Please [edit] your question to zoom the far too large image in on the table of contents, where the little red exclamation points show in the table of contents, and ask about them.

Comment: Looks like broken links to me when you move from one to another. I would suggest use Save AS as a copy to another.

Answer (score 6):

Data is not stored in the MXD, so if you move only the MXD the data will not be moved as well.

If the data is moving with the MXD, then under File > Map Document Properties check off "Store relative pathnames to data source".

If the data is not moving with the MXD then make sure the path where the data is stored is accessible on the new machine.

Answer (score 0):

Mxd does not store the data. If you are using another computer you can share your map as a package then it will carry the data with it as well.
or
Shift your data along with the mxd file to another computer then link your data to mxd file using the details given in the following link.
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/repairing-broken-data-links.htm